# React Map GL caches error when running in sandbox

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I am trying to run the following in a  sandbox environment but I keep running into the below error

```
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'caches' property from 'Window': Cache storage is disabled 
because the context is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
at dt (<anonymous>:566:12382)
at <anonymous>:566:14870
at <anonymous>:566:15177
at wt (<anonymous>:566:15230)
at kt (<anonymous>:566:16193)
at Object.getSession (<anonymous>:566:11811)
at Object.processRequests (<anonymous>:566:12233)
at Object.queueRequest (<anonymous>:566:9815)
at Object.getSessionAPI (<anonymous>:566:12004)
at Map._authenticate (<anonymous>:570:376250)`
```